# Can't connect to a mapped drive, but can RDP into computer. What could cause this?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, mapped-drive

I have a Windows Server 2012 computer, and I can RDP into it. Previously I was able to access a shared folder via a mapped drive, but I'm unable to do this now. What could cause this?

the network drive is definitely share with me. Someone played with Okta's multi-factor authentication on the server (which prevented me from RDPing, but this has since been removed). I am on Windows 10, and have probably installed updates over the last couple weeks.

Other than that I can't see what has changed that I would not be able to access the mapped drive.

Comment: A share needs 2 things: the share itself must have your name in its allowed list (its shared to you), and the security settings on the files themselves must also allow you to work with them. If either isn't setup correctly, you can't access the files. If security groups are used in a domain, you need to reboot before these settings become in effect.

Comment: Both are accessible to my user. Also, I previously was able to access this shared drive

Comment: An admin can remove your permissions and it would give you exactly what you have now. Just because you used to have it in the past doesn't mean you have now. Ask your system administrator to find out why you can't access the share anymore.

Comment: I am the admin. And I didn't remove my permissions. In fact I tried that and readding them